# Morphism into K-analytic projective space $\mathbb{P}_K^{n,rig}$

Tags: rigid-analytic-geometry

Let $K$ be a local field, with a completed algebraic closure $\hat{\bar{K}}$ and $A$ be an affinoid $K$-algebra. Is it then true, that for $f_0, \ldots ,f_n \in A$, the map $\phi:$ Sp$A \rightarrow$ $\mathbb{P}_K^{n,rig}, x \mapsto [f_0(x):\ldots:f_n(x)]$ defines a morphism of rigid spaces?

I know by a lecture a similar result for varieties, but the proof I have is not applicable in this case.

EDIT: To clarify what it means. For $f \in A$ and $x \in$ Max$A$, $f(x)$ is the residue class in $A/x$, which can be embedded in $\bar{K}$, so $f(x) \in \bar{K}$, is determined up to conjugation. Points in $\mathbb{P}_K^{n,rig}$ are also meant as equivalence classes of conjugated elements of $\mathbb{P}^{n,rig}(\hat{\bar{K}})$ (see https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/pschnei/publ/pap/xsymm.pdf, page 8)

I thought what you need is

1. $\phi$ is continuous with respect to the Grothendieck topology of rigid spaces
2. for all admissible open $U \subset \mathbb{P}_K^{n,rig}$ and for all $f \in \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_K^{n,rig}}(U)$, we have that $f\circ \phi_{|\phi^{-1}(U)} \in \mathcal{O}_{\text{Sp}A}(\phi^{-1}(U))$, i.e we have a map $\phi^*_U:\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_K^{n,rig}}(U) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\text{Sp}A}(\phi^{-1}(U))$ compatible with restrictions

As rigid geometry is relatively new for me, both points, if true, are at the moment not obvious for me and I don't know what a good way could be to verify this.

Comment: Let $R>0$ that is bigger than all the norms on the $f_i$'s on $\mathrm{Sp}(A)$. Then, you have a bounded morphism from the Tate algebra $K \langle R^{-1} \underline{T} \rangle$ to $A$, hence a morphism from $\mathrm{Sp}(A)$ to a disc of dimension $n+1$. You can embed the latter into $\mathbb{A}^{n+1,\mathrm{rig}}_K$ and then project onto $\mathbb{P}^{n,\mathrm{rig}}_K$. Is this want you wanted?

Comment: Mmmh not sure. I got it from https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/pschnei/publ/pap/xsymm.pdf, page 10. I added some lines to hopefully clarify the situation.